# Import existing SVN local copy into WebStorm

Tags: svn, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use WebStorm, which I guess isn't too different from IntelliJ. I also have several SVN repos checked out on my local, and I'm trying to import them into WebStorm. Simply opening up the directory in WebStorm and enabling VCS integration (SVN) in the project does not appear to be enough to make WebStorm recognize the SVN properties of the directory, however. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I've made it work before but I don't remember how. For several reasons, I do not want to do another checkout of the files.

Comment: If "checked out repo" means "working copy", you should have a directory called `.svn` and that's indeed everything that any JetBrains IDE needs.

Comment: in theory, yeah. But that's not how it's working right now.